# lulc mapping from modis surface reflectance

Tags: classification, modis

can i prepare LULC with 10 classes from MODIS surface reflectance level 3 data 500m resolution... if so what are the preprocessing techniques should i do on the data..i have to prepare LULC for yearly 2000-2014 for western ghats on a regional scale . will the size of training sets alter the accuracy of LULC? i tried Maximum likelihood classification with green,NIR,red combination and there was a lot of variation from year to year and the map was not accurate. i didn't process the data as it was already processed level 3 .